# HTML Email : How do I remove spacing between 2 tables? Gmail specificially

Tags: html, css, email, gmail, html-email

Is it me or is gmail bulls**t?
On outlook/browsers my email is perfect but on gmail there is a space between 2 tables, WHY?!?
Picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/54zYl.png

[image]

Please do not tell me cellspacing,padding or border space they are all already in the code. If you can help me I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance!!

Code:

```
<body style="margin:0; padding:0">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;">
        <tr>
          <td VALIGN="bottom"> 
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vyJu43v.png">
          </td>
          <td VALIGN="bottom">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/opinionmatters_"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/vSAgEXE.png"></a>
          </td>
          <td VALIGN="bottom">
           <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/opinion-matters"> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Ih5jtiC.png"></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0">
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="4" VALIGN = "top">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/9B9Wcit.png">
          </td>
          <td>
<p style="font-family:arial; color:#002d62;">The new Insight Snapshot newsletter from Opinion Matters is packed full of research<br/>and communication ideas to inform your next project. Featuring tips for data<br/>storytelling, ways to interact with your target audience through online quizzes and<br/>case study examples of recent international survey campaigns.</p>

<p style="font-family:arial; color:#002d62">Read online <a href="http://www.opinionmatters.com/insightnewsletter.html" style="">here</a> or <a href="http://www.opinionmatters.com/index.php/contact-us">request a printed copy</a></p>
          </td>
          <td rowspan="4" VALIGN = "top">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/lNwkYpL.png">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/79k0VgK.png">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="70">
          <td height="70">
<p style="font-family:arial; color:#002d62;">If you would like to speak to a member of the team regarding any of the features in<br/>the newsletter please call 0207 251 9960 or email <a href="mailto:newsletter@opinionmatters.com" style="text-decoration:none; color:#002d62">newsletter@opinionmatters.com</a></p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td VALIGN = "bottom">

            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/brGmdjG.png">
          </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <p style="color:#85808e; font-size:14px; text-align:center">Data Protection: We will not pass your details on to any third party or send you unsolicited mail. If you would like<br/>
to unsubscribe from this and any future mailings please unsubscribe <a href="" style="text-decoration:none;color:#85808e">here.</a><br/><br/>markettiers4dc trading as Opinion Matters. Registered office: Northburgh House, 10a Northburgh Street,<br/>London, EC1V 0AT. Registered in England & Wales No. 4308785 VAT number 783 037 913. CIPR Partner, ISO<br/>9001:2000 registered (Certificate Number GB7041)</p>
  </body>
```

Comment: Why don't you use only one table instead?

Comment: If you are looking at the mail in GMail, can't you open the dev tools and inspect the problematic element in order to see what stlyes have been applied and where they come from?

Comment: If I use one table then the size of a cell under the row directly above will be the same if you understand what I'm saying. Everyone who does HTML emails makes multiples tables depending on the design. I did use the dev tools but its really hard to explain but it doesn't help even if I change the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now used to `img` tag with `valign="top"`

```
<img src="xyz.png" valign="top" />
```

**as like this**

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;">
        <tr>
          <td VALIGN="bottom"> 
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vyJu43v.png" valign="top">
          </td>
          <td VALIGN="bottom">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/opinionmatters_"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/vSAgEXE.png" valign="top"></a>
          </td>
          <td VALIGN="bottom">
           <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/opinion-matters"> <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Ih5jtiC.png" valign="top"></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0">
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="4" VALIGN = "top">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/9B9Wcit.png">
          </td>
          <td>
<p style="font-family:arial; color:#002d62;">The new Insight Snapshot newsletter from Opinion Matters is packed full of research<br/>and communication ideas to inform your next project. Featuring tips for data<br/>storytelling, ways to interact with your target audience through online quizzes and<br/>case study examples of recent international survey campaigns.</p>

<p style="font-family:arial; color:#002d62">Read online <a href="http://www.opinionmatters.com/insightnewsletter.html" style="">here</a> or <a href="http://www.opinionmatters.com/index.php/contact-us">request a printed copy</a></p>
          </td>
          <td rowspan="4" VALIGN = "top">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/lNwkYpL.png">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/79k0VgK.png">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="70">
          <td height="70">
<p style="font-family:arial; color:#002d62;">If you would like to speak to a member of the team regarding any of the features in<br/>the newsletter please call 0207 251 9960 or email <a href="mailto:newsletter@opinionmatters.com" style="text-decoration:none; color:#002d62">newsletter@opinionmatters.com</a></p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td VALIGN = "bottom">

            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/brGmdjG.png">
          </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <p style="color:#85808e; font-size:14px; text-align:center">Data Protection: We will not pass your details on to any third party or send you unsolicited mail. If you would like<br/>
to unsubscribe from this and any future mailings please unsubscribe <a href="" style="text-decoration:none;color:#85808e">here.</a><br/><br/>markettiers4dc trading as Opinion Matters. Registered office: Northburgh House, 10a Northburgh Street,<br/>London, EC1V 0AT. Registered in England & Wales No. 4308785 VAT number 783 037 913. CIPR Partner, ISO<br/>9001:2000 registered (Certificate Number GB7041)</p>
```

**[What is Vertical Align](https://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/)**

Comment: I can't actually believe this worked, wow thanks a lot man, you made my day been trying to fix this for a long time.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried using `margin-top:-5px` for second table , i think this should remove the space .